# TimeZoneInfo - Per user or systemwide?

Tags: c#, .net, timezone

I'm trying to figure out if the `System.TimeZoneInfo` is a local user or system wide setting? I've been modifying my local timezone as the user i'm logged in as, but a service running in the background as system that is logging the timezone seems to continually log the old time zone. If the TimeZoneInfo is per user, then is there a way I can lookup the list of timezones for all users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're really talking about [`TimeZoneInfo.Local`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.local.aspx)? I believe that's a system-wide setting *but* it's cached on a per-process basis. You can call [`TimeZoneInfo.ClearCachedData()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.clearcacheddata.aspx) to force a refresh - although obviously you've got to know to do so :) If you're running a background task which needs to pick up on changes, you could always just call it once every 5 minutes... I don't think that would be a huge performance hit, if you can live with it being stale for up to 5 minutes.

(It seems odd to me that changing the system time zone doesn't appear to require privileged access - in Windows 7 at least - but hey...)

Comment: Big thanks! Now I see the large message on MSDN that TimeZoneInfo.Local is cached :S

Answer (score 1):

TimeZone is systemwide, it's not a userwide settings. But your problem is that .NET caches the current timezone to reset the cache:
`System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.ClearCachedData();`

Answer (score 1):

Timezones are a system setting. (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation).